# Nuxt 3 DOM bindings not updating with ref value update

Tags: javascript, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

Please see minimum viable reproducible repo [here](https://github.com/ashmenon/debugging-nuxt-reactivity/tree/master). To reproduce the error, please load this page in a browser with a viewport wider than 767 pixels.

### The issue

I'm having an issue with the `:class` binding on an element in my component. I've extracted the issue into a repo linked above.

Essentially I have a composable called `isMobileDevice` that uses the `window.matchMedia` approach, and returns a `ref`. When I use the ref as a text value directly in the component, it is reactive (but breaks hydration, which is a side question). But when I use it as part of `:class`, the associated class never disappears from the DOM element even though the value is no longer `true`. If I look at the property via Vue DevTools (I tried defining a separate variable inside the `setup` just to see if it updates), the value correctly shows as `false`.

### The questions

- Main question: is there something I need to do to cause the DOM element to also update when a `ref` updates?
- Side question: in Nuxt 3 I notice that a change in text value (e.g. `<p>foo</p>` to `<p>bar</p>`) breaks hydration (as mentioned above as well), whereas in Nuxt 2 it did not. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

#### Edit

Adding the repo code in here for easier viewing. It's the same code as is in the repo:

```
./app.vue
=========
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Testing Nuxt reactivity</h1>
    <p>We are testing the boolean value <span class="mono">isMobileDevice</span>, which is a composable.
    </p>

    <hr>

    <p :class="{'is-blue': isMobileDevice }">
        This text should be blue if it's a narrow device. (testing binding to a class)
    </p>

    <hr>

    <p>
        The value below is the <span class="mono">isMobileDevice</span> boolean getter property, and will break hydration if loaded on a wide page:<br>
        {{ isMobileDevice }}
    </p>

    <hr>

    <p>
        The value below is <span class="mono">isMobileDevice</span> property wrapped in a <span class="mono">ClientOnly</span> tag, and updates correctly<br >
        <ClientOnly>
            <template #placeholder>

            </template>
            {{ isMobileDevice }}
        </ClientOnly>
    </p>

  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

const foo = isMobileDevice;
watchEffect(() => {
    console.warn("Foo has updated", foo.value);
})

</script>

<style scoped>
.is-blue {
    color: blue !important;
}

.mono {
    font-family: monospace;
    color: orange;
}
</style>
```

```
./composables/screenSizes.ts
============================
import { ref, watchEffect } from "vue"

const useMedia = (query: string, defaultValue = false) => {
    const matches = ref(defaultValue)

    watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
        if (process.server) {
            return
        }

        const media = window.matchMedia(query)


        if (media.matches !== matches.value) {
            matches.value = media.matches
        }

        const onChange = () => {
            matches.value = media.matches
        }

        media.addEventListener("change", onChange)

        onInvalidate(() => {
            media.removeEventListener("change", onChange)
        })
    })

    return matches
}

export const isMobileDevicComp = computed(() => {
    return useMedia("(max-width: 768px)", true)
})

export const isMobileDevice = useMedia("(max-width: 767px)", true)
export const isMediumPortraitDevice = useMedia("(max-width: 959px)", false)
export const isMediumDevice = useMedia("(max-width: 1024px)", false)
export const isLargeDevice = useMedia("(max-width: 1200px)", false)
```

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?